# How do you prevent and able to give error message if a data has already existed in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Event and has 2 columns - eventID (Primary key, auto incremental, used for relationships, int data type) and an eventName(nvarchar(50) data type).  How do I prevent duplication of data/value in my eventName column?  I would like to return a message to the user that an event has already occurred through my asp.net page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `UNIQUE` constraint on `eventName`

[UNIQUE Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> You can use UNIQUE constraints to make sure that no duplicate values
>   are entered in specific columns that do not participate in a primary
>   key. Although both a UNIQUE constraint and a PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   enforce uniqueness, use a UNIQUE constraint instead of a PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint when you want to enforce the uniqueness of a column, or
>   combination of columns, that is not the primary key.
>
> Multiple UNIQUE constraints can be defined on a table, whereas only
>   one PRIMARY KEY constraint can be defined on a table.

Also have a look at [Creating and Modifying UNIQUE Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177420%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [SQL UNIQUE Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Comment: How?  What's the procedure to do that in SQL Server (Visual Studio)?

Comment: @user3195396 Can wej ust say "it starts with opening the documentation and searching for "unique constraint". It also helps to click the hyperlink in the answer and - ah - read the pages that this links to and - ah - other related pages.

Comment: @TomTom being snarky doesn't help